# d/m/Y date with each value repeated

Tags: php, date, datetime

Time format: `09:58:46.0000000`, datetype: time,

Date format: `2014-05-28`, datetype : date

When I try to print results:

```
echo "<td>" .date_format( $row['time'], 'H:i:s') . "<hr>";"</td>";
echo "<td>" .date_format( $row['date'], 'dd/mm/YY') . "<hr>";"</td>"
```

The script returns time in format `10:02:16` (that is good)

But date is in the format `2828/0505/20142014`. Why?

Comment: If `H:i:s` is hour:minute:second, why would you use `dd/mm/YY`? That is datedate/monthmonth/yearyear.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea how people can come up with these questions...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath becouse i think u born with programer skills. Many peaples learning all the time...

Answer (score 0):

The proper way is

```
echo "<td>" .date_format( $row['date'], 'd/m/Y') . "<hr>";"</td>"
```

You were attempting to use `d`,`m`,`Y` twice , that's the reason for weird output

You could try reading http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

for more information regarding date formatting

Answer (score 0):

You must pass proper formatting string for `PHP` function `date_format`.

```
echo "<td>" .date_format( $row['date'], 'd/m/Y')
```

Check [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Change this to

```
date_format( $row['date'], 'dd/mm/YY');
```

this

```
date_format( $row['date'], 'd/m/Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
echo "<td>" .date_format( $row['date'], 'd/m/Y') . "<hr>";"</td>"
```

Check [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for more information.